# How to define a single entity in doctrine annotations, map it and update the database in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

So. I already have some existing Entity PHP files, which have had their getters and setters done and been applied to the database.
Now I want to add a new entity, get it's getters and setters done and applied to the database. This is what my Entity annotation file looks like:

MyEntity.php

```
<?php
// src/Me/MyBundle/Entity/MyEntity.php

namespace Me\MyBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="MyEntity")
 */
class MyEntity
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", unique=true)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $MyEntityID;
}
```

What commands should I use to do just 1 entity, rather than all of them?

e.g. to do all of them, I do this under PHP CLI:

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities Me\MyBundle
```

And then, using sudo Bash and then su - www-data

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:create
```

(I have to do this as www-data otherwise I get a permission denied from dev.log)

Although that requires me to delete the existing tables. I could use:

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update
```

But that complains unless I use --force

What are the commands I need to create getters and setter for this one, new, entity and add it to the DB.

Thanks.

Comment: So you just want to generate the getters and setters for your newly created entity and afterwards update your database schema ? what IDE/text-editor are you using if any? Getter/Setter generation is integrated in most IDEs with php support or can be added to them with a plugin.

Comment: I am trying to do it the "symfony" way. e.g. use Doctrine2 to do it.

Comment: I'm using `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force` most of the time during development and never had an issue. Only downside is that it's not capable of preserving the column order.

Answer (score 2):

For generating getters and setter to single entities you give them in a shorthand notation to the command:

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities MyCustomBundle:User
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities MyCustomBundle/Entity/User
```

for upgrading existing databases you should take a deep look at the [DoctrineMigrationsBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html) and generate a migration class, which does the update.

Comment: Surely there should be something for adding new tables (entities), or does Symfony/Doctrine seem to believe bundles magically appear, fully formed without any need for new tables. It seems well geared for deploying production bundles, but lacking in regards to developing said bundles in the first place.

Comment: As I said, the DoctrineMigrationsBundle is for your use case.

Comment: This is the problem I get with using the command you mentioned: 'Generating entities for namespace "MyBundle\Entities\MyEntity"' That sounds promising. Then it throws the error: [Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException]
  Invalid mapping file 'Me.MyBundle.Entity.Me.MyBundle.Entity.SomeOtherEntity.orm.yml' for class 'Me\MyBundle\Entity\Me\MyBundle\Entity\SomeOtherEntity'. Why is it fiddling with other existing entities when I told it just to do the one I was interested?